# Writing (composing) start-end notification on XMPP with strophe

Tags: xmpp, strophe

How can we send a notification to the other party when a client began to writing? (And also when ended up writing)

Answer (score 2):

Strophe (and the other party) would need support for [XEP-0085 Chat State Notifications.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) IIRC strophe doesn't support XEP-0085 yet.